# Scaling text to fit within FabricJS Textbox when changing text value programmatically

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using a FabricJS `Textbox` in my canvas application to allow users to edit text.  This is working fantastically for me, as I want text to wrap during editing, and wrap/unwrap as the width of the box is shrunken and expanded.

However, I have a secondary use case that I need some guidance on.

Occasionally, I need to replace the `text` in the textbox programmatically.  In this scenario, I do **not** want the textbox to wrap text or expand when the text is too long for the width.  Instead, I would like to reduce the `fontSize` so that the text fits on one line.

Note: I only do this text replacement once when the canvas is loaded (or just before in the JSON).

I currently handle this with `IText` using the following code, but I cannot seem to modify it in a way that works reliably with `Textbox`.  I also lose out on the fantastic text wrapping if I use IText, which is why I'm evaluating this.

```
const handleTextChanged = ({ target }: { target: fabric.Object }) => {
  const { fixedWidth, width, fontSize } = target

  if (width > fixedWidth) {
    // Shrink the font size to stay within the max width
    target.fontSize = Math.round((fontSize * fixedWidth) / (width + 1))
  }

  target.width = fixedWidth
}
```

Is there a way to achieve something like this using just Textbox?  That is, I would like to keep text wrapping and unwrapping functionality during normal editing, but I would also like to load text in programmatically and have the font size scale to fit the box when I load the canvas.

Comment: Are you open to a scrollable text solution?

Comment: Apologies, I'm actually talking about FabricJS, not the native `<textbox`.  I will update the question

Answer (score 0):

```
const originalWidth = element.width;
   element.set({ objectCaching: false, text: data2.value.toString() })
   if (element.textLines.length > 1) {
   do {
   element.set({ width: element.width + 5 });
   }
   while (element.textLines.length > 1);
   element.set({ scaleX: originalWidth / element.width });
   }
```